# how to validate spring applicationContext.xml file

Tags: java, spring

I have couple of beans defined in the applicationContext.xml file and found if I made mistake(say typo) with the bean's name, spring won't complain anything and go ahead load the invalidate configuration. doesn't spring do the checking automatically? and how can i implement schema validation on the applicationContext.xml file? thanks.

Comment: If the file isn't valid, Spring won't load it. If it loads it, it's valid. It does its own schema-level and logic-level validation.  You need to give us a concrete example of what you think its doing wrong.

Comment: in the following code, i actually mistyped the class name, which should be 'com.xyz.services.serviceAttributesConfigInitializer', however Spring wont' complain anything exception wont start the service.
  <bean class="com.xyz.services.service.AttributesInitializer">
    <constructor-arg value="${attributes_sources}" />
    <constructor-arg ref="operationalConfig" />
  </bean>

Comment: That's not true.  It *will* complain, and it will complain a lot. You must not be looking at the correct log file.

Comment: I would love to be able to validate in a junit test. Not everyone on the team uses a nice IDEA and testing the xml files by having Spring load them is very time consuming -- 2 or 3 minutes is not uncommon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA has a wonderful [support](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/spring_framework.html) for Spring, including:

- detecting broken references (bean does not exist, has a wrong type, etc.)
- completing bean names when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is pressed (along with narrowing the list to only the beans matching by type)
- discovering missing/duplicated beans when `@Resource`/`@Autowired` is used and it will fail to autowire at runtime
- quick navigation between Java and application context XML
- ...and **lots** more

Also I strongly recommend writing Spring smoke [integration test](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html). It doesn't have to test anything, just context startup (you would be amazed, how many errors it discovers).

Comment: how can i test the context startup using itegration test? do you have any examples or links? thanks.

Comment: Please read the [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html) I provided. Everything is explained there. Having one test exercising most of your application context XML files will have a great value, even when no actual testing is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid errors in spring context I suggest you to use a plugin which checks its contents, for instance [springIDE](http://www.springsource.org/springide/release-20) or [SpringSource Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts). In this way the plugin validates your spring contexts during development and you can find errors before the execution of your application.

Comment: i wish to write code to check the bean manually instead of having Spring do it automatically, in that way i can get a hold of the control...is that possible?

Comment: I don't know, I've never done that. I like to do validation during development, so I don't have any problems during execution time. The point is that Spring tries to parse the context, and if there any errors it is not able to do that and so it throws the related exception...But, I get curious, what do you want to do exactly? Can you post an example please?

Answer (score 1):

in addition to this problem , i had problems with detecting duplicate bean ids that would get overridden unintentionally among others but finally i found this open-source project that helps you write JUnit unit tests that going to detect these problems. it was very easy to use and solved my problemsm it's called [Beanoh](http://www.beanoh.org/)